# Existence of constant in( 0,1)

Tags: real-analysis

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{3+2x_n}{3+x_n}$$ (a) Show that there exists $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that for all $n\geq 2$, $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq \lambda |x_n-x_{n-1}|$.

Here how to show the existence of such constant. It is clear that $x_n$ is an increasing sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $C^1$ function $f$ and any $a\leq b\in \mathbb R$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 f(b) - f(a) 
 & = &
 \int_0^1\frac{d}{dt} f(tb + (1 - t)a)) \; dt\\
 & = & 
 (b - a) \int_0^1 f'(tb +(1 - t)a)\; dt. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Crash through with absolute value to get 
\begin{equation*}
|f(b) - f(a)| \leq |b - a| \max_{a\leq x\leq b}|f'(x)|. 
\end{equation*}
Now apply this with $f(x) = (3 + 2x)/(3 + x)$. We have 
\begin{equation*}
 f'(x) = \frac{3}{(3 + x)^2}. 
\end{equation*}
Since the sequence $x_n$ you've specified is increasing, this answers your question as long as $-3< x_0$ is not too close to $-3$.